# Themeless Citrix + Kerio + Outlook Programming

Tags: outlook, mapi, citrix, outlook-redemption

Does anybody know something about the constellation of Outlook on Themeless Citrex server and integrated kerio ?

We use some outlook api for retreving and sending mails with outlook.-

But we got some weired problems.

For example Some times we gert a "MAPI NOT FOUND" exception when trying to create mails. Or sometimes outlook tells me that it has connection problems (without further details),

Sometimes we get a -2147216347 as error result and so on..

Can someone give some good points to look after? Any hints or anybody with similar problems?

Some problems can simple be reproduced when using VB Script which sends mails or uses GetEntryById with MAPI / Redemption.

Outlook uses the clustered featured and may not be running on the same server as the host process.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be more specific - waht is the relevant snippet of your code that produces teh problem?
I will respod to your personal e-mail and send you the debug version of the dll.